# Basing an FF Neural network on Vector3

Tags: neural-networks, modeling

I'm having some fun with Unity and neuralnets.
At first I've based it on an array of `float`s.

It had 8 inputs and 3 outputs:
2 eye inputs for x,z coords
2 nose inputs for x,z coords
3 wall inputs for a,b,c distances
1 for current health

which resulted in
3 floats for movement x,y for direction and a for speed

Than I had the idea to use `Vector3`'s instead of floats.
My guess was that this way spatial movement will be more "organic" to the system.

Now it takes 4 Vector3's and outputs two. (the seconds magnitude is used for speed)

Surprisingly it worked pretty well. Consistently the first 2 generations has members that avoids walls and eats food. Of course not very well, but they are doing things that before needed at least 10-20 generations to reach this level.

Is this special? I mean just because I'm feeding in (forward) vectors the output is more reasonable?

[Float version](https://github.com/zelding/NeuralNetwork/blob/4de822ae90b07d74e604c602e87aed2d033d0e72/Assets/Scripts/NeuralNetwork.cs)
[Vector3 version](https://github.com/zelding/NeuralNetwork/blob/3d/Assets/Scripts/Math/VectorNet.cs)